# Getting the all values of dataframe against duplicate values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first ever post to Stackoverflow. Have recently started to learn Pandas and pretty much learning the nits bits of this incredible library.

In below dataframe, can I get the dataframe based on only duplicate values in my 'value' column. I have tried groupby and .duplicated. but unable to get the required O/P

Input df:

```
Name    ID  Date    Value
a   NSW 19/05/2018  290
b   NSW 19/05/2018  340
c   VIC 19/05/2018  340
d   NSW 19/05/2018  70
e   VIC 19/05/2018  130
f   NSW 19/05/2018  175
g   VIC 19/05/2018  260
h   NSW 19/05/2018  350
i   VIC 19/05/2018  350
```

O/P required

```
Name    ID  Date    Value
b   NSW 19/05/2018  340
c   VIC 19/05/2018  340
h   NSW 19/05/2018  350
i   VIC 19/05/2018  350


Data['Duplicate']=Data.duplicated(subset='Azimuth', keep=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there,
Try this,

```
out=df[df.duplicated(subset=['Value'],keep=False)]
print out
```

Output:

```
Name   ID        Date  Value
1    b  NSW  19/05/2018    340
2    c  VIC  19/05/2018    340
7    h  NSW  19/05/2018    350
8    i  VIC  19/05/2018    350
```